# KeyError when bbox_inches='tight' in mplfinance plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror, mplfinance

I have the following code:
from pandas_datareader import data as web

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta  
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib as plt
df = web.DataReader('goog','yahoo', start="2021-07-3", end="2021-09-12")
mpf.plot(df, style='charles', type = 'candle', volume=True, figratio=(12,8), bbox_inches='tight')
```

`bbox_inches='tight'` is throwing an error:

```
KeyError: 'Unrecognized kwarg="bbox_inches"'
```

How can i make margins tight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use kwarg **`tight_layout=True`**.

If that doesn't do what you want you can also try kwarg `scale_padding` [**as described here**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/212#issuecomment-655603896).

`bbox_inches` can only be used in conjunction with kwarg `savefig` kwarg.  [**See here**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/savefig.ipynb) for details.